# How to get info for Battery Life on CLBeacons?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I work with CLBeacons and i want to get data about CLBeaocn battery life.
Does anyone know how to get remaining battery life on CLBeacon?

Comment: [Check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207687/accessing-battery-level-of-battery-powered-ibeacon-devices-mainly-kontakt-io-on). It might be vendor dependent.

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter?

Answer (score 2):

There is no method on the iBeacon API to get battery life. Some devices may have a non-standard way to get battery status information via the Bluetooth API.