# Read battery Level of a iBeacon

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ibeacon

I have to do the reading of the battery level of a iBeacon. As I was researching is not possible using the protocol cllocation right ?. The recommendation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207687/accessing-battery-level-of-battery-powered-ibeacon-devices-mainly-kontakt-io-on) tell me it is reading the data packet with bluetooth Protocol,I have the description of the data packets kontakt [Data packet description](http://docs.kontakt.io/beacon/kontakt-beacon-v1.pdf). But as I read these data? how I can read data from a iBeacon in specific. Thank you.

Comment: It depends of your iBeacon. Does it advertise it?

Comment: Thats what i think because i can't read the data package.

Comment: As it's said on your "recommandation" link, it's not with the iBeacon part (which in iOS is with CoreLocation.framework), but in the "classical" BLE part, which use CoreBluetooth.framework. What happen if you you scan for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iBeacon API won't allow you to read the battery level. You might be able to read it using Core Bluetooth. Kontakt provides a shortcut to get the battery level in the scan response package which is convenient, but proprietary. Kontakt also implements the [BLE Battery Service](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.battery_service.xml) 0x180F which is a more generic way to get the battery level. You'd need to connect and read the value of Characteristic 0x2a19 to get the battery percent.

Unfortunately not all beacons will advertise the battery service. Estimote sends battery information back in one of it's proprietary services.

Comment: Thanks but, How does estimote to send information about the battery? They send that information in the same cllocation protocol or not?

Comment: @NeilGarcía Go to playstore and download Estimote application to configure and to check the battery level you want to.