# How to get battery level of Kontakt ibeacons

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

The ibeacon beaconlayout for kontakt is
m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25

I am using altbeacon [library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library) for android for detecting it but i am unable get the battery level of the beacon an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207687/accessing-battery-level-of-battery-powered-ibeacon-devices-mainly-kontakt-io-on) says that they are transmitting the power level but i am unable to fetch it. Further the comment on [this](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconParser.java) page (from line no 100 to 103) describes the byte structure hope this helps.

How can i get the battery level from the beacon.

Comment: Have you managed to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your beaconlayout expression is correct for that beacon, then you can read the battery value for the d25-25 data field with:

```
long batteryLevel=beacon.getDataFields().get(0);
```

See documentation for reading data fields here:

http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/javadoc/org/altbeacon/beacon/Beacon.html#getDataFields()

However, the first link in your question mentions the field is in the "scan response" of the beacon.  If that statement is true and not a misstatement, that means the battery level is not in the advertisement at all, so you will not be able to get it without separately polling for this info.

Comment: By using the above code i got an long value so i thought this is the battery level but i was wrong the battery level is not in advertising packet its in the scan response as can be found [link](http://docs.kontakt.io/beacon/kontakt-beacon-v2.pdf) @davidgyoung can please elaborate what do you mean by separately polling. please direct me in right direction.

Comment: If the battery level is in the scan response, then the library will not allow you to read those fields, as it only provides access to advertisement sent by the beacon.  The scan response is a separate packet.  You would have to write custom Android code to read the scan response from the beacon.  I would suggest opening a new question about how to read Bluetooth LE scan responses on Android.

Comment: Hello, my beacon layout is m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24 i cant get the value of batteryLevel value. how to do that ?

Comment: Try the beacoon layout in the question.  It has a ,d25-25 at the end.

Comment: @davidgyoung Sir i set this d:25-25 at last.. m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
beacon.getDataFields().get(0).toString() => 0 value as result.. this code is in setRangeNotifer's didRangeBeaconsInRegion what should i do ? i used http://www.minewtech.com/ i4 Pilot beacon

Comment: Sorry, this technique will not work as the battery level has been moved to the scan response for Kontakt.io beacons.  You need custom Bluetooth code to read it.

Comment: @Vrajesh: Thank you for providing the beacon layout. Works perfect with onyx beacons

Comment: So it's not working on Kontakt.io beacons? In my case it gives me Beacon.id3(1003) || dataField(0):= 16
Beacon.id3(1001) || dataField(0):= 16
For two different beacons one with 90% and other with 70%. I am using the same layout as the OP and this is logged data from loop for all datagields(only one exists)?
If someone has the answer is it possible to give me a link or refference?!