# How to get the battery level from Kontakt.io beacons using AltBeacon API

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, ibeacon, altbeacon, kontakt.io

I need to get the battery level from the kontakt.io beacons. I have set the layout as below and the **DataFields** are empty when I read the beacons in **RangingBeaconsInRegion**.

I was expecting I could read the battery level from the last bit as described in the Kontakt.io documentation.

This is my current code:

```
private BeaconManager InitializeBeaconManager()
{
    BeaconManager bm = BeaconManager.GetInstanceForApplication(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context);

    var iBeaconParser = new BeaconParser();
    iBeaconParser.SetBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25");
    bm.BeaconParsers.Add(iBeaconParser);

    _rangeNotifier.DidRangeBeaconsInRegionComplete += RangingBeaconsInRegion;

    bm.Bind((IBeaconConsumer)Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context);

    return bm;
}

void RangingBeaconsInRegion(object sender, RangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Beacons.Count > 0)
    {
        var beacon = e.Beacons.FirstOrDefault();

        var data = beacon.DataFields.FirstOrDefault();
        // here DataFields is empty!

    }
}
```

I am using Xamarin Forms and this is the code for the Android Version.

Is this possible? or do I need to use the Kontakt.io API?

**UPDATE**

I have removed all parsers before apply the new layout and I am able to read the dataFields. However, I am getting a value **8** which I have no idea what this value means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get battery level of Kontakt ibeacons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885659/how-to-get-battery-level-of-kontakt-ibeacons)

Comment: I saw similar questions but the problem I got in mine was the fact that I didn't clean all the **BeaconParser** before apply the new layout. See @davidgyoung answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not positive the syntax on Xamarin, but try removing all existing beacon parsers before adding your custom one.  I suspect the built in iBeacon parser is still active And it is matching first.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have removed the default parsers and I am now getting a value. The value is 8 (long) and looking in the Kontact.IO app the battery claims 93%. What 8 means?!

Comment: The raw value will range from 0-255.  You have learned that 8 apparently means 93℅.  You will need a few more data points to come up with a conversion formula.  You might ask Kontakt.IO.  unfortunately their SDK is closed source so we cannot see for ourselves.

Comment: Thank you! You gave me a good help. I will contact Kontakt.IO and find out what the value means.

Answer (score 0):

The battery level in Kontakt.io beacons are part of their "[scan response packet](https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/201492522)", not part of the iBeacon structure, you'll have to use [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/CoreBluetooth/) to read [Characteristic 1, Service 5](https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/201493072).

A quick breakdown of how this works is also [described here](https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/206294004), and the recently launched [Xamarin component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/KontaktSDK) uses [the same CoreBluetooth approach](https://kontakt.io/blog/deliver-great-mobile-apps-with-the-kontakt-io-ios-sdk-for-xamarin/).