# How can we get Beacon battery life from iOS Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

hey i want to get beacon battery life information from an iOS device 
is there a solution for that..

i've done many researches but nothing  .. ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207687/accessing-battery-level-of-battery-powered-ibeacon-devices-mainly-kontakt-io-on))

**UPDATE** :

i found the solution : i'm working with IBKS beacons : and they have a CBCharacteristic (FFF8), it allows you to get the battery level in extra byte

- if it can helps someone 
  i found it in the general attributes Tables (GATT) ([here](http://ibeacon.accent-systems.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/GATT-iBKS105-FV.1.pdf))

Comment: Most beacons probably don't advertise this information. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207687/accessing-battery-level-of-battery-powered-ibeacon-devices-mainly-kontakt-io-on

Depends on what product you're using. If you're talking about using an iOS device as an iBeacon, then that information definitely isn't advertised with the bluetooth signal.

Comment: As said in the linked answer, it's not a standard and no one is obliged to advertise it. If your beacons does it, either you know how to read it (looking at its doc), either you try to reverse engineering it.

Comment: Agreed previous comments, it's up to the manufacturer to advertise this info. A good example: the well known Estimote manufacturer provides an API for their iBeacons, and they provide battery info [as mentionned in their docs](http://estimote.github.io/iOS-SDK/Constants/ESTBeaconPower.html).  Could you check if your iBeacon manufacturer provides such info?

Comment: thank you for your response i will check for some info from the iBeacon manufacturer